# JavaScript extra possible character in regex expression

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I'm making a program about music chords. The first character has to be a single letter A through G. The second letter can contain an optional either "#", "b" or "" (nothing at all). And then I want a capital M followed by a 7.

For example, in one of my boolean statements I want `"AM7"` and `"F#M7"` to both evaluate to true, for both being a major chord in music theory.

Would this be something like:

```
/([A-G]{#b''}{M7})/$.test("GbM7");    //Should be true
/([A-G]{#b''}{M7})/$.test("GbbM7");    //Should be false
/([A-G]{#b''}{M7})/$.test("Gbm7");    //Should be false
```

I know the code above is wrong, but I am trying to illustrate my throught process of what i  am going for. I feel like I am really close.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: What is it that you think the `{ }` groups do?

Comment: Well the regex part for "either '#', 'b', or nothing" would be `[b#]?`

Comment: What is the `$` after the regexp for?

Comment: I'm dumb. I thought the curly braces were used when there was a set set value that it could take on, as opposed to a range. I also thought that the money sign was used to end a regex. Sorry, regex is really hard for me to grasp for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `?` to mark something optional.

```
/[A-G][#b]?M7/
```

Comment: So how would that be different if you could have up to five characters at the beginning? Like lets say "ABCDE#M7" would also be considered valid. Do the "[ ]" denote just a single character in this range, or could it be many different?

Comment: You could use a quantifier in that case: `/([ABCDE][#b]?){1,5}M7/`

Comment: @Team.Coco `[A-G]{1,5}` will match from 1 to 5 occurrences of that pattern.

Comment: awesome. Thanks guys

Comment: For completeness, you might want to use beginning and end markers to rule out partial matches: `/^([A-G][#b]?){1,5}M7$/`.  Otherwise, a string like `'dinosaurA#M7'` would pass.

Comment: @buttonupbub It depends on whether this is for validation of a whole string or searching text for a match.

Comment: Couldn't I just use '/[A-G]{1}[#b]?M7/' instead? Does this mean that that it must start with a single letter A-G?

Comment: `{1}` is the default for any pattern, it matches 1 time unless there's a quantifier that modifies that.

Comment: @Team.Coco Rather than asking all these questions, go read the tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: then how is "dinosaurA#M7" even a possibility? Is it because the regex looks for a string within the given test string to match with?

Comment: Ok. Will do. Thanks!

Comment: @Team.Coco That is correct.  A search for a match for the regular expression is performed within the string.

Comment: @Team.Coco Because it matches anywhere in the string, unless you anchor with `^` and/or `$`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the expression you are looking for is

```
/[A-G][#b]?M7/
```

The `?` marks the previous element (`[#b]`) as optional.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I chose the above as best answer since they posted just a few seconds before you, but I appreciate your response!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Just joined Stack Overflow.  Wow, these answers come out fast.